# eclipse lost all my (android) projekts/ how to repair the workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, workspace

my PC crashed yesterday and all my eclipse projects are gone since than. They are still in the File system but eclipse doesn't show them. I made a new workspace and imported all projects. But now android support v7  disappeared  form my build path. I didn't include that project, the project wizard did it for compatibility reasons. Now i want to fix the problem and eclipse offered me to chooses, "add project 'android-support-v7-appcompat' to build path of 'my project'" or "add archive 'andoird-support-v7-appcompat.jar -path to android-support-v7-appcompat\libs'" . Which should i choose and why?